# set dynamic width with only CSS?

Tags: css, dynamic, width

I have a title (h1) which is centered on the page. I want to add lines to the left and right of the title, so that they fill the rest of the page's width.
However, I want the lines to adapt to the title's width, which is dynamic. So, I want the line's width to be dynamically calculated.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/cAEqE/1/

In the example I set the lines' width to 35% so they could get the effect that I want. However, if the title is longer, it will break into 2 lines, and I don't want that to happen.

My boss told me to avoid javascript, so it would be excellent to use only CSS. However, if this turns out to be impossible, I will turn to good old jQuery.
Cheers!

Edit: the website has a background-image, so I can't use a background on the h1. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 10px;
}

#title {
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #97999C;
    height:10px
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="title">
    <h1>TITLE TEST</h1>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cAEqE/27/

**UPDATED**

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cAEqE/63/

Comment: This is actually a good idea, thank you. However, I have a background image, so I can't set a background to the h1 or the designer will kill me. I will edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `div`s for the lines, you should use a background image on the parent `div`.

For example, your HTML would be much simpler:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>TITLE TEST</h1>
</div>​
```

And your CSS would be:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    background-color: white;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 30px;
}

#content {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    background:transparent url(https://jira.atlassian.com/s/en_UKtovngv/725/4/1.0/_/images/mod_header_bg.png) repeat-x left center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I've stolen a fair bit of this code from Jira which does [basically what you're after](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/DEMO).